¿こうする es expresión o dos palabras juntas? / Is こうする an expression, or two words together?

こうするしか...

¿「こうする」 es una expresión o son palabras separadas 「こう」 + 「する」?


こうするしか...

Is 「こうする」 an expression, or are they two separate words 「こう」 + 「する」?

Creo que solo se permita preguntas en Ingles o Japones.

@istrasci, no hay problema.

In the phrase 「こうするしか...」, we have three words:

こう: "like this, in this way"
する: "to do"
しか: a kind of limiter, like "there's nothing but [whatever comes before this word]"

The two-word piece こうする meaning "to do like this" can be changed to any of the こそあど words:

こうする: "to do like this, to do in this manner"
そうする: "to do like that, to do in that manner", closer to the listener than the speaker
ああする: "to do like that, to do in that manner", far from both listener and speaker
どうする: "to do like how, to do in what manner", for an indeterminate or for a question


En la frase 「こうするしか...」, tenemos tres palabras:

こう: "como esto, en esta manera"
する: "hacer"
しか: un tipo de limitador, como "no hay nada excepto [lo que viene antes de esta palabra]"

La pieza de los dos palabras こうする, que significa "hacer como esto", se puede cambiar a cualquiera de las palabras de こそあど:

こうする: "hacer como esto, hacer en esta manera"
そうする: "hacer como eso, hacer en esa manera", más cerca del oyente que del hablante
ああする: "hacer como eso, hacer en esa manera", lejos de los ambos, del oyente y del hablante
どうする: "hacer como cual, hacer en cual manera", para una indeterminada o para una pregunta


Supposedly for ああする, you could explain it with "hacer como aquello, hacer en aquella manera".
